# How to detect a new branch is created at gitlab remote through gitl-ci.yml

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to detect if a new branch is detected in the remote. Based on that I would like to run pipeline jobs in the Gitlab. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Where do you want to detect the new branches? On a different server or on Gitlab CI itself? Do you have a job defined in your `.gitlab-ci.yml ` yet? As far as I know a job should run for any branches if you don't specify a specific branch.

Comment: In GITLAB-CI itself. If I would like to run a specific job only on creation of new branch in the gitlab and the job should be neglected for the further commits happening in the branch.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how to run jobs based on the pipeline? You can specify which branch the job is for: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#complex-trigger-syntax

```
staging:
  stage: deploy
  trigger:
    project: my/deployment
    branch: stable
```

Comment: I would like to run a job only when the any new branch is created. It also should not run for the further commits happening in the branch. Branch name can be anything.